# Tkinter program converted to .app using PyInstaller closes immediately

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller, .app

Have a Tkinter battleship game application I wrote that I am trying to convert to an `.app` file so I can run it easily on Mac OS X computers. After using `cd` to navigate to the directory with both the main `.py` file, and all the subfiles (three other Python files, a json file, and an icon file), I am executing the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon favicon.icns --name Battleship battleship.py
```

This produces two files in the "dist" folder: `Battleship` and `Battleship.app`. The `Battleship.app` has the icon I specified in the command above.

When I run the non `.app` file (via double-clicking it), a terminal window opens and my Tkinter GUI opens and works (from the little testing I did) flawlessly. However, I would like *only* the GUI to open, without the terminal.

This is supposedly the purpose of also producing the `.app` file. However, when I run the `.app` file (via double-clicking it), it's icon merely bounces a few times in my application bar at the bottom of my screen, and then disappears. No actual window is opened.

How do I make it so when I double-click the `.app` file, my application's GUI actually opens (without a terminal window)?

Using Python `3.5.1`.

Comment: You can use the `--noconsole` option in your terminal command to avoid showing the terminal window in your compiled `.app` file.

Answer (score 0):

RoberR seems like you are missing some necessary packages while building app from pyInstaller, I would suggest your to use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon favicon.icns --name Battleship battleship.py
```

it will display your terminal and you would be able to figure out what is happening, in case of missing package please use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-imports=file_name --icon favicon.icns --name Battleship battleship.py
```

Hope this solves your problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely an issue with Tkinter that crash when using the doubleclick on the .app. The only workaround I found was to use "brew python3" instead of "anaconda python3".

Answer (score 0):

Reposting myself from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818744/10143204

There is a few issues with the tcl version that comes with python, [discussed here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820). I've written an script that automatically changes the init.tcl file to the correct version.

N.B. you shouldn't use the `--onefile` flag as the file directories aren't present, and the script won't work.

1. `cd /path/of/your/app`
2. `git clone https://github.com/jacob-brown/TCLChanger.git`
3. `pyinstaller --windowed app.py`
4. `python TCLChanger/TCLChanger.py`

You should now be able to open your app, from the terminal and via double clicking.

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fileTCL' referenced before assignment