# PyInstaller executable doesn't show GUI

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I'm currently working on a program that accepts a specific file as input, works on the data and provides two graphs through Matplotlib (the only module imported in the data parsing file).

For this I have made a small GUI for the user to choose the file to have a graph made of. (w/ tkinter and PIL imported).

I have to make an app out of this and I'm using PyInstaller to it. Unfortunately I haven't been able to make the final file work (or run properly).

---

I have already made several modifications either to the code itself, but also to the PyInstaller's .spec file.

I have added the function to fix the path for PyInstaller.
I have modified the .spec file to add the path to an image, not to show the console.
I have tried with these settings both on/off: UPX, One File.
I have checked the log files for missing modules as everything seems to be ok.

---

Some of the code:

Imports on the GUI file:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import rectifierDataParser
```

Imports on the Data Parsing file:

```
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

GUI File:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.fileButton = tk.Button(self, text(...))
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text(...))
        self.fileButton.pack(side = 'top')
        self.quitButton.pack(side = 'bottom')

    def load_file(self):
        filename = askopenfilename(title = "Select file", filetypes = [("Files", ("*.001", (...)))]
        rectifierDataParser.main(filename)

    def resource_path(relative_path):
        try:
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

app = Application()
app.master.title('Graphing Data')
app.master.geometry('300x200')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.jpg"))
panel = tk.Label(app, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
app.mainloop()
```

---

As I'm currently not able to see the GUI on the screen, is there any problem with the code itself or any compatibility with PyInstaller (supposedly PyInstaller is fully functional w/Tkinter).

I hope one of you might help me have a breakthrough as I have been stuck on this for way to much time! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is a few issues with the tcl version that comes with python, [discussed here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820). I've written an script that automatically changes the init.tcl file to the correct version.

N.B. you shouldn't use the `--onefile` flag as the file directories aren't present, and the script won't work.

1. `cd /path/of/your/app`
2. `git clone https://github.com/jacob-brown/TCLChanger.git`
3. `pyinstaller --windowed app.py`
4. `python TCLChanger/TCLChanger.py`

You should now be able to open your app, from the terminal and via double clicking.

Comment: Getting error - "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fileTCL' referenced before assignment" in the 4th step. Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem and I fixed it by editing the .spec file.

I had to set

```
console=True
```

You'll find this option in the bottom of your .spec file.

Something like this:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='YOU/EXECUTABLE/NAME',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
```

If you do not find your .spec file you can generate one by running

```
pyi-makespec yourprogram.py
```